# How pass a block into Rails.application.config.assets?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets

I'm writing rails 4 application and I'm trying to refactor assets.rb file.

Currect state:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.enabled = true
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.prefix  = '/sprockets'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(404.html 500.html)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << %w( big array of css files)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << %w( big array of js files)
```

What I want to see:

```
Rails.application.config.assets do |assets|
  assets.enabled = true
  assets.version = '1.0'
  assets.prefix  = '/sprockets'

  assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/plugins"
  assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/html"

  assets.precompile += %w(404.html 500.html)
  assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf|swf)\z/

  # css
  assets.precompile << %w( big array of css files)

  # js
  assets.precompile << %w( big array of js files)
end
```

Is it possible to pass a block of code into `Rails.application.config.assets` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible because assets doesn't expect s block if you look at its signature. You can pass it, but it won't have any effect on assets.

Comment: very bad. thanks. what about pull request to rails? :)

Comment: @bmalets, no need, try create a temp variable being equal to Rails.application.config.assets and work with it. I can't check if it works right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with rails but something like this might work as a work-around:

```
def configure_assets obj
  yield obj
end

configure_assets(Rails.application.config.assets) do |asset|
  asset.enabled = true
  asset.version = '1.0'
  # ...etc....
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tap`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.tap do |assets|
  assets.enabled = true
  # ...
end
```